# Is this the correct way to use pthread?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, thread-synchronization

I am trying to create an HTTP server using multi-threading. *main()* hands off the client_sock from *accept()* to one of the worker threads. If no worker threads are available, it waits until one is. I am restricted to not being able to call *accept()* within the worker threads. Here is a portion of my code so far. Some questions I have are:

1. Do I need to use 2 pthread mutex and condition variables as I do right now?
2. Do I need to use pthread lock or unlock at all in these cases?
3. If I wanted to add a mutex lock when files are being created on the server, would I have to create another mutex variable or would one of the existing ones work?

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <err.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define SIZE 1024

struct shared_data
{
    int redundancy;
    int client_sock;
    int working_threads;
    int dispatch_ready;
    pthread_mutex_t* dispatch_mutex;
    pthread_mutex_t* worker_mutex;
    pthread_cond_t* dispatch_cond;
    pthread_cond_t* worker_cond;
};

void* receiveAndSend(void* obj)
{
    struct shared_data* data = (struct shared_data*) obj;

    int bytes;
    char buff[SIZE + 1];

    while(1)
    {
        while(!data->dispatch_ready)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(data->dispatch_cond, data->dispatch_mutex);
        }
        data->dispatch_ready = 0;

        data->working_threads++;

        client_sock = data->client_sock;

        bytes = recv(client_sock, buff, SIZE, 0);

        // do work

        data->working_threads--;
        pthread_cond_signal(data->worker_cond);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2 || argc > 6)
    {
        char msg[] = "Error: invalid arg amount\n";
        write(STDERR_FILENO, msg, strlen(msg));
        exit(1);
    }

    char* addr = NULL;
    unsigned short port = 80;
    int num_threads = 4;
    int redundancy = 0;
    char opt;

    while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "N:r")) != -1)
    {
        if(opt == 'N')
        {
            num_threads = atoi(optarg);

            if(num_threads < 1)
            {
                char msg[] = "Error: invalid input for -N argument\n";
                write(STDERR_FILENO, msg, strlen(msg));
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        else if(opt == 'r')
        {
            redundancy = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // error (getopt automatically sends an error message)
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // non-option arguments are always the last indexes of argv, no matter how they are written in the terminal
    // optind is the next index of argv after all options
    if(optind < argc)
    {
        addr = argv[optind];
        optind++;
    }

    if(optind < argc)
    {
        port = atoi(argv[optind]);
    }

    if(addr == NULL)
    {
        char msg[] = "Error: no address specified\n";
        write(STDERR_FILENO, msg, strlen(msg));
        exit(1);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = getaddr(addr);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    int serv_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(serv_sock < 0)
    {
        err(1, "socket()");
    }

    if(bind(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        err(1, "bind()");
    }

    if(listen(serv_sock, 500) < 0)
    {
        err(1, "listen()");
    }

    // Connecting with a client
    struct sockaddr client_addr;
    socklen_t client_addrlen;

    pthread_mutex_t dispatch_mutex;
    pthread_mutex_init(&dispatch_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_t worker_mutex;
    pthread_mutex_init(&worker_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_t dispatch_cond;
    pthread_cond_init(&dispatch_cond, NULL);
    pthread_cond_t worker_cond;
    pthread_cond_init(&worker_cond, NULL);

    struct shared_data data;

    data.redundancy = redundancy;
    data.dispatch_ready = 0;
    data.working_threads = 0;
    data.dispatch_mutex = &dispatch_mutex;
    data.worker_mutex = &worker_mutex;
    data.dispatch_cond = &dispatch_cond;
    data.worker_cond = &worker_cond;

    pthread_t* threads = new pthread_t[num_threads];
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, receiveAndSend, &data);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        data.client_sock = accept(serv_sock, &client_addr, &client_addrlen);

        while(data.working_threads == num_threads)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(data.worker_cond, data.worker_mutex);
        }

        data.dispatch_ready = 1;
        pthread_cond_signal(data.dispatch_cond);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why have a complicated handoff protocol rather than just having every worker thread that's idle call `accept` itself?

Comment: It's for a university assignment, I just asked if we could do it that way but unfortunately we can't.

Comment: In that case it makes sense -- they're teaching a principle that could be used for lots of other worker-thread applications, just using webserver as an example.

Comment: Don't include <iostream> in a C program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many very basic bugs in your program, which pretty clearly demonstrate that you don't understand locks and condition variables (or appropriate use of pointers).

A lock protects some shared data. You have exactly one shared data item, therefore you should need exactly one lock (mutex) to protect it.

A condition variable indicates that some condition is true. Reasonable conditions for your use case would be `worker_available` and `work_available`. (Naming your condition variables `dispatch_cond` and `worker_cond` does not help clarity.)

A condition variable is *always* associated with a mutex, but you don't need two separate mutexes just because you have two condition variables.

---

On to the bugs.

This code is obviously buggy:

```
    while(1)
    {
        while(!data->dispatch_ready)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(data->dispatch_cond, data->dispatch_mutex);
        }
```

From `man pthread_cond_wait`:

> atomically release `mutex` and cause the calling thread to block on the condition variable `cond`

How can this thread *release* a mutex if it never acquired it?
Also, how can this thread read `data->dispatch_ready` (shared with other threads) without acquiring a mutex?

This code:

```
    struct shared_data data;

    data.redundancy = redundancy;
    data.dispatch_ready = 0;
    data.working_threads = 0;
    data.dispatch_mutex = &dispatch_mutex;
    data.worker_mutex = &worker_mutex;
    data.dispatch_cond = &dispatch_cond;
    data.worker_cond = &worker_cond;
```

isn't buggy, but has unnecessary indirection. You could make `dispatch_mutex` and condition variables be *part* of `shared_data`, like so:

```
struct shared_data
{
    int redundancy;
    int client_sock;
    int working_threads;
    int dispatch_ready;
    pthread_mutex_t dispatch_mutex;
    pthread_mutex_t worker_mutex;
    pthread_cond_t dispatch_cond;
    pthread_cond_t worker_cond;
};
```

And here is the most subtle bug I noticed:

```
        data.client_sock = accept(serv_sock, &client_addr, &client_addrlen);
...
        data.dispatch_ready = 1;
        pthread_cond_signal(data.dispatch_cond);
```

Here, you will wake up [at least one](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cond_broadcast.3p.html) of the threads waiting for `dispatch_cond`, but may wake up more than one. If more than one thread is awoken, they all will proceed to `recv` on the same `client_sock` with potentially disastrous results.

**Update:**

> How do I fix this.

Probably the best and most performant way to fix this is to have a queue of "work items" (using e.g. a double-linked list with head and tail pointers), protected by a lock.

Main thread would add elements at the tail (while holding a lock), and signal "not empty" condition variable.

Worker threads would remove head element (while holding a lock).
Worker threads would block on "not empty" condition variable when queue is empty.

Main thread may continue adding elements when queue is full (all workers are busy), or it may block waiting for a worker to become available, or it can return "429 too many requests" to the client.

Comment: Thank you! For the last part of your answer, doesn't ```pthread_cond_signal``` only wake up one thread waiting on that condition? I thought it was only ```pthread_cond_broadcast``` that woke them all up.

Comment: @Justin You are partially correct. The man pages says "The pthread_cond_signal() function shall unblock at least one of the threads that are blocked on the specified condition variable cond (if any threads are blocked on cond)." It may unblock more than one.

Comment: Even if multiple threads wake up from ```pthread_cond_signal```, doesn't only one of them ever leave the while loop?

Comment: @Justin No. "wake up" means "return from `pthread_cond_wait`". All of them will check the `dispatch_ready` approximately simultaneously, and all _may_ observe value 1 and exit the loop.

Comment: So how do I prevent that?

Comment: @Justin It is very important to understand that a condition variable is *stateless* and it is your responsibility to keep track of all system state that your program needs to keep track of. If you need to keep track of whether or not a thread has been dispatched to read from the socket, then you need to keep track of that in some shared variable somewhere.

Comment: @Justin I've updated the answer with a potential fix.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Thanks, but isn't ```accept()``` already a queue of incoming connections? I am trying to use that to my advantage by only storing one connection at a time in my variable.

Comment: @Justin `accept` is a queue of incoming connections, but the point of your exercise is to be able to handle more than one client, so you _can't_ use `accept` as your sole queueing mechanism.